# Migrate from Manifest V2 to Manifest V3

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

I need to migrate from Manifest V2 to Manifest V3 and I did the changes for manifest.json file. But I don't understand how it's should be updated in background.js file beacuse this extension was developed by someone else. Below you can find the code for background.js.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this error.
[![Error msg][2]][2]

````
  function (e) {
    var urlretained = e.url.replace(/&id=/g, ',');
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.open(
      'GET',
      'https://*/*/,
      true
    );
    xmlhttp.send();
  },
  {
    urls: [
      'https://*/*',
      'https://*/*',
      'https://*/*',
    ],
  }
);```


  
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnTFA.png
````

Comment: Convert the code that uses XMLHttpRequest to use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Thanks so much for you reply. Would it be possible to get the updated code, please?

Answer (score 1):

As also mentioned by wOxxOm ...

> [Cross-origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/xhr/)
>
> ⚠️ Warning
>
> In Manifest V3, `XMLHttpRequest` is not supported in background pages (provided by Service Workers). Please consider using its modern replacement, `fetch()`.

Here is an example code using `fetch` from [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```js
async function logJSONData() {
  const response = await fetch("http://example.com/movies.json");
  const jsonData = await response.json();
  console.log(jsonData);
}
```

Please note that your code is incomplete e.g. it is not possible to get `https://*/*/`.